# Do you know about any source/feed/api with the latests matches of a football team?

Tags: php, xml

Do you know about any source/feed/api with the latests matches of a football team? I need to implement a plugin for a website that will fetch for every post about a team, the last 5 results of that team.

Thank you!

Comment: It is not football season so the last 5 results will be the same for a while, 2.5 months.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was interested some years ago. If free, you can use data from http://www.football-data.co.uk/data.php. Data in `csv`: history and current results. You can "fetching" results by team title (thinking,its`s slowly). By there only top european championships.

Comment: Please _do not_ encourage obviously off-topic questions by answering them. You should know better after two years!